# Express.js routes management for large web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, express.js, url-routing

I'm currently working on a large web application with numerous routes.  Currently, our routes are in one large list in a single JSON file.  We recently ran into a problem due to the precedence of params being set from top to bottom in the file.  This question details the issue we encountered further: [Node.js Express route naming and ordering: how is precedence determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17735610/3522930)

My plan is to propose an alternate routing solution based on my work from a personal project.  I feel like it's a valid suggestion but missed out on a chance to really make my case in a meeting the other day.  Here is a `routes.js` file from my personal project that demonstrates the pattern I would like to use, let me know what you think or of possible better alternatives/edits.  Thanks!

By creating separate routers for each resource, different controllers can access the same URLs without the params being overridden.

```
const express = require('express');

const usersRouter = express.Router();
const songsRouter = express.Router();
const playlistsRouter = express.Router();

const usersController = require('../controllers/users');
const songsController = require('../controllers/songs');
const playlistController = require('../controllers/playlists');

usersRouter.route('/')
  .post(usersController.create)

songsRouter.route('/')
  .get(songsController.index)
  .post(songsController.create)

playlistsRouter.route('/')
  .get(playlistController.index)
  .post(playlistController.create)

songsRouter.route('/:id')
  .get(songsController.show)
  .put(songsController.update)
  .delete(songsController.destroy)

playlistsRouter.route('/:id')
  .get(playlistController.show)
  .put(playlistController.update)
  .delete(playlistController.destroy)

module.exports = {
  songs: songsRouter,
  playlists: playlistsRouter,
  users: usersRouter,
};
```

A couple questions that come to my mind are:

1. How optimal it would be to have all those Express router instances?
2. Is this approach scalable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolutely, you should compose your express application in terms of a hierarchy of routers

1. instancing all those routers should be negligible in terms of your application's performance
2. this is the only approach i can imagine feasibly maintaining at scale, it buys you some separation of concerns